# vue execute @click after v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a checkbox with a state based on todo.complete
`todo.save()` persists the current complete value to the database. However `@click` seems to be triggered before the v-model binding updates `todo.complete`

```
  <v-checkbox v-model="todo.complete" @click="todo.save()" :label="todo.title" />
```

I have to do it like this to make it work:

```
  <v-checkbox v-model="todo.complete" @click="todo.complete = !todo.complete; todo.save()" :label="todo.title" />
```

Is there some way to execute `todo.save()` after v-model has been updated. something like `@click.after`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try using the `change` event instead:

```
<v-checkbox v-model="todo.complete" @change="todo.save()" :label="todo.title" />
```